# Replace specific breaks line in csv

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I need to replace these "specific" breaks lines in csv output file. Thanks for any help.
For example:

```
"1.","",""
"2.","Combi","SCK Test 1"
"3.","",""
"4.","",""
"5.","",""
"6.","Combi","SCK
Test 2"
"7.","",""
"8.","",""
"9.","",""
"10.","Combi","SCK Test 3"
"11.","",""
"12.","",""
"13.","",""
"14.","",""
"15.","",""
"16.","Combi","SCK Test 4"
"17.","Combi","SCK
Test 5"
"18.","Combi","SCK Test 6"
"19.","Combi","SCK Test 7"
"20.","Combi","SCK Test 8"
```

Here is my code, but it replaces all of them

```
Dim FSO As Object
Dim Filename As String
 
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Filename = "F:\Docs\data.csv"

text = FSO.OpenTextFile(Filename).ReadAll

FSO.OpenTextFile(Filename, 2).Write Replace(text, vbLf, ",")

Debug.Print FSO.OpenTextFile(Filename:=Filename, IOMode:=ForReading, Format:=TristateUseDefault).ReadAll
```

Comment: Not much of a VB guy but what is vbLf? When you say specific line breaks which ones are you wanting to replace? Blank lines?

Comment: Is it the Test 2 and Test 5 lines that are spit into 2?

Comment: `FSO.OpenTextFile(Filename, 2).Write Replace(text, "SCK" & vbCrLf & "Test", "SCK Test")`
- you may have to experiment with the particular line-feed character, e.g. by copying your data into a text file, using `vbLf` did *not* have the desired effect

Comment: Yes, they are unquoted lines. The text is variable.

Answer (score 2):

Process each line in turn adding the linefeeds where appropriate.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveLF()

    Dim FSO As Object, ts
    Dim Filename As String, n As Long
    Dim s As String, sep As String, sOut As String
     
    Filename = "F:\Docs\data.csv"
    
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = FSO.OpenTextFile(Filename)
    Do While ts.AtEndOfStream = False
        n = n + 1
        s = ts.ReadLine ' without line ending
        If Left(s, 1) = Chr(34) Then '"
            sep = vbCrLf
        Else
            sep = " "
        End If
        If n = 1 Then sep = ""
        sOut = sOut & sep & s
    Loop
    sOut = sOut & vbCrLf  ' last line
    
    Debug.Print sOut
End Sub
```